# DB update issue - when posting the list of records, few records are not getting updated - Using Spring JPA, Jersey Rest, Postgresql DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.6

The use case is: I have 2 spring boot microservices, with jersey rest and spring jpa with postgres DB. Here one service is posting to other service sequentially list of records to update. Out of 90-100 records, 1 or 2 records data is not getting updated(here there was another api which is created this data, the issue is happening during the update).

Even for the record for which data is not updated, its child data is getting persisted properly. There is only one table that has the issue.
code flow for update:

```
hospRepository.saveFlush(hospital); 
hospBranches.forEach(branch -> hospBranchRepo.saveAndFlush(branch));
hospPatients.forEach(patient -> hospPatientRepo.saveAndFlush(patient));
```

Here the hospital has list of patients and list of branches which are the childs and these are getting updated, only the parent is not getting updated. There is no cache that is enabled in this case.

And i am unable to see any exception being thrown. Able to see the the query going all the way through JDBC, using tcpdump. and with the returned object if i try to print the updated data i am able to see, but in DB still the old data is available.

Tried keeping the delay between 2 requests, added synchronized block and tried with pure jdbc update for that particular entity still the issue persists.

Could someone please provide your insights on this.

Comment: Could add the queries you see? Maybe also with https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Comment: did you check also directly PGSQL logging: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/12/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs ?

Comment: Hi Luca & Hauser, yes tried printing the sql statements in logs, i am able to see the SQLs still the data is not getting persisted. used tcpdump to see the jdbc traffic able to see that as well. quite strange that still the in the db data is not persisted. it is not happening for all the records. only 1/2 out of 90+ records.